# Android - Compare strings from Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This has to be a really easy answer. I've been searching and searching on how to compare a variable to a string in Java. I have an Intent and only want to declare some vars if data from the intent matches. Surely this can't be that hard. Java is frustrating to me. :)
I know that type will equal message at some point but it doesn't work. 
e.g.

```
String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");

 if(type.equals("message")){
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            String avatar = intent.getStringExtra("photo");
            count = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("count"));
            Bitmap photo = getBitmapFromURL(avatar);
            String theMessage = Html.fromHtml(msg).toString().replace("\\", "");
        }
```

**EDIT:**

I did output type to log as suggested and it does show `message` like it should. I am trying to us the same variable `theMessage` and `photo` but it complains that its not declared so it prompts a fix and puts this at the top. Is this what's causing it not to work? This is a notification by the way.

```
private static String theMessage = null;
private static Bitmap photo = null;
```

I try to do this later in the code but it complains about not being declared.

```
 if(type.equals("message")){
        notification.setSubText(theMessage);
        notification.setLargeIcon(photo);
        }
```

So that is what I have and with the static vars it doesn't work at all even after the error of not being declared goes away.

Comment: String type = intent.getStringExtra("type"); Try to log the value you are getting in type.

Comment: Your string comparison is okay. Unfortunately, you're not even saying what's not working for you. One thing is for sure, your code is not robust; e.g. if there's no "type" extra in the intent, your app will crash.

Comment: supporting @ClassStacker's comment: it's worth reversing the method call: `"message".equals(type)` to prevent NPE (`NullPointerException`). It may be more confusing to call a method on a `String` constant, but useful to do so (extract to a constant / `static final String` if too confusing).

Comment: What I meant by not working is it just ignores the statement because the vars are never used and photo is not displayed. But like Class says if there isn't an extra available it crashes. Thats why I wanted the condition. I can try using hasExtra() for the type if that will work and make it more robust.

Comment: @Pjack You can simply follow TwisterRob's advice or check for `null` results. If the API says a method can return `null`, it's often not a bad idea to be able to deal with that.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I also changed my code to prevent NPE ad TWisterRob suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

String type = extras.getString("type");
Log.i("type", type);

if(type.equals("message")){
    String msg = extras.getString("message");
    String avatar = extras.getString("photo");
    count = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("count"));
    Bitmap photo = getBitmapFromURL(avatar);
    String theMessage = Html.fromHtml(msg).toString().replace("\\", "");
}
```

and see the logCat what comes against type.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi see my update. I am getting `message` when I logCat it but I think its the 2nd statement that is not working which is part of the notification builder. I'm trying to do the same check because I don't want to use those parameters unless type = `message`. I hope that's clear.

Comment: I'm getting `message` which is correct. I believe I know my problem now, just don't know how to fix. For some reason Java won't let you access the variable outside of that if statement. I get `cannot be resolved to a variable`. But I know it does. I've only dealt with Java for less than a week so it's hard debugging something I know little about. :/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe I figured it out. I needed to create local vars for `Bitmap photo = null; String theMessage = null;` The statement was fine before but the private final declaration was messing it up. I really have A LOT to to learn with Java. I used to PHP and things such seem to work with that. :)

Comment: No problem! Thats really fine that you figured it yourself! I thought it at first but then it came to my mind that you may have declared them somewhere in your code.